# Datastax - Cassandra Amazon EC2 Multiregion Setup - Cluster with 3 node

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I have launched 3 Amazon EC2 instance and setup datastax cassandra as follows

**1.Region - US EAST:**

**cassandra.yaml** - configuration

a.listen_address as private IP of this instance

b.broadcast_address as public IP of this instance

c.seeds as 50.XX.XX.X1, 50.XX.XX.X2 (public-ip of node1,public-ip of node2)

**cassandra-rackdc.properties** - configuration

dc=DC1

rack=RAC1

dc_suffix=US_EAST_1

**2.Region - US WEST:**

I did same procedure as I did above.

**3.Region - EU IRELAND:**

**The result of above configuration is**

All the node working good individually. But when I do

*$nodetool status* on all the three node

It only listing the local node only.

I tried to achieve the following things.

**1.** Launch 3 cassandra node in three different region. For say, US-EAST,US-WEST,EU-IRELAND.

2. With Following configuration or methodology

   a.Ec2MultiRegionSnitch

   b.Replication staragey as SimpleStrategy

   c.Replication Factor as 3

   d. Read & write level as QUORUM.
3. I wish to attain only one thing i.e. if any two of the region is down or any two of the node down, I can survive with renaming one node.

**My Questions here are**

Where I did the mistake? and How to attain my requirements?

Any help or inputs are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me with cassandra 3.0

```
endpoint_snitch: Ec2MultiRegionSnitch
listen_address: <leave_blank>
broadcast_address: <public_ip_of_server>
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: <public_ip_of_server>
-seed: "one_ip_from_other_DC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the resolution of my issue. I am using replication strategy as SimpleStrategy, hence I do not require to configure **cassandra-rackdc.properties**.

Once, I removed the file cassandra-rackdc.properties from all node, Everything working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that SimpleStrategy is [not recommended](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html) for production.

Comment: Thanks for your note. However, we are right now using this infrastructure for development purpose only.